# Focus is unpredictable when dismissing keyboard using iOS / VoiceOver / Safari

Tags: html, ios, safari, voiceover

When I use VoiceOver and Safari on iOS, and fill in a text field, and dismiss the keyboard with the "Done" button, it is unpredictable where the focus will land. The only consistent thing I'm seeing is that it's never actually on the form control that I was typing in.

Is there an explanation for what VoiceOver focuses on when the keyboard is dismissed with "Done"?